# Is it ever safe to not wait for SaveChangesAsync()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, async-await

Consider the following WebAPI method:

```
[HttpPost]        
public async Task<IHttpResult> CreateWorkItem(Item wi)
{
    var item = await dataContext.Item.AddAsync(wi);
    await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

Is there a situation where it would be safe not to `await` for a `SaveChangesAsync()` method?

In theory I would have a faster response time if I just sent a response while the flushing to database gets done in the background.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: "Is there a situation where it would be safe not to await for a SaveChangesAsync() method?" => No, there's none. You would have a faster response time because the context would be disposed and nothing would be saved

Comment: you mean the thread would dispose and cance the `SaveChangesAsync()` even without finishing it? isn't it going to continue asynchronously?

Comment: No, it's not. No-one knows that you created that private task so it will be left to no-one to ensure that it can finish successfully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing magical about the `await` keyword. It quite literally means "wait on this task to complete before moving on". Tasks return hot, or already started, so whether you await them or not, the work is happening.

However, things can get dicey in situations where you don't wait for task completion. In particular, here, your context, which is required to actually do the save operation (remember that it owns the physical DB connection) is request-scoped. That means if you do not await the save and return from the action, you're now essentially in a race to see which completes the first: the save operation or the end of the request. If the end of the request (i.e. the final response is flushed to the client) occurs first, the context is disposed taking the active transaction and your SQL connection with it.

Another important reason to await is for proper exception handling. If you do not await, any exceptions thrown during the save will essentially be swallowed because the code has already moved on. That means you have no real assurances that the save *actually* completed successfully; all you've got is a wish and prayer.

With *very* rare exception, all async tasks should be awaited all the time. It doesn't always need to be in the same line (such as when using things like `Task.WhenAll` to await a series of tasks), but at some point or another the await keyword should be there. FWIW, those rare exceptions are mostly confined to desktop and mobile development where you often need to fire work off on new threads to prevent blocking the main, or UI, thread. That's not remotely a concern for web applications, so you can pretty much consider the "await all the things" rule universal in that context.

Comment: Don't you (usually) only need new threads if the work being done is CPU bound? You can still await I/O in WinForms without spawning a new thread. I thought that the reason you don't have to await all the time in WinForms is due to the event loop. (Not sure how mobile works.)

Comment: Not necessarily. It's quite common to to run even I/O bound work on new threads as async alone is not a guarantee of not tying up the UI thread. Async allows the potential for thread switching, but does not guarantee it, so while it may be *more* important for CPU-bound work (as async isn't even an option there), it's still important to start new threads with async I/O work sometimes, depending on what's being done.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I/O-bound async relies on I/O completion ports, which are not threads. So how would that tie up the UI thread? The only instance I'm familiar with this not being the case is where you have fake-async, such as Oracle's libraries, where you have an async wrapper over synchronous code.

Comment: It's not that the thread is tied up necessarily, but it also may not be released. For some operations, that may not be a big deal, but it can cause UI stalls in certain scenarios. Again, not as important as CPU bound work, but you can't just universally say this is async so I'm going to run on the UI thread.